# Detect repeated CSS properties of a styled component in Vscode

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I would like to detect repeated CSS properties in my styled components.

Something like

```
const TextContents = styled.div`
  --> display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  --> display: flex;
`;
```

Is there anything you know of that could help, please?

Ideally inside of Vscode or even with a command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) can do this.

The rule that does the check is called [declaration-block-no-duplicate-properties](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-block-no-duplicate-properties/).

By installing the official [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint), you'll be able to see inline errors, but you can also use the command-line tool to automatically fix this type of error, with the [`--fix`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/options#fix) flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simone. Does this work for styled components?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there is tooling to make Stylelint work with styled components. See here: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#stylelint
EDIT: just a heads up that it appears to be deprecated - see [this issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3607)